# Проблеммы с Dagger 2: FATAL ERROR

Tags: android, dagger2

Приложение собираеться но падает с

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.testdagger1.MaxsControl.AppComponent.inject(com.example.testdagger1.MainActivity)' on a null object reference
```

AppCommand:

```
@Component(modules ={AppMobile.class, ButtonControl.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {

     void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

App:

```
public class App extends Application {
private static AppComponent component;
public static AppComponent getComponent()
{
    return component;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject
ButtonControl bt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    App.getComponent().inject(this);
 }
}
```

ButtonControl (Этот класс чисто тестовый):

```
@Module
public class ButtonControl {

    public void ButtonControl(Context Ct)
    {

    }
}
```

AppMobile:

```
@Module
public class AppMobile {

    private Context appContext;

    public AppMobile(Context context)
    {
        appContext=context;
    }

    @Provides
    Context providesContext()
    {
        return appContext;
    }
    @Provides
    public ButtonControl provideDownloadfilePresenterImp() {
        return new ButtonControl();
    }
}
```

Пытался по этой статейки что то сделать, но ничего получилось даже элементарное... 
https://habr.com/ru/post/279125/

SOS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В статье на хабре всё объяснено(на сколько dagger возможно было объяснить). Dagger тяжело понять, в действительности это очень элементарная штука. Весь принцип строится на построение графа. 
Проблема уходит в файл класс `App`

Ваш код описывает граф, но кто его инициализирует? Как я вижу из кода - никто. И у вас получается так:

1. Создаётся `MainActivity`
2. Вызывает `App.getComponent()` что бы заинджектить себя.
3. В `App` происходит `return component;` который возвращает `null` ведь `component == null`
4. В `MainActivity` начинается иньекция `App.getComponent().inject(this);` но в действительности это выглядит вот так `null.inject(this);` и выбрасывается `NullPointerException`.

В статье есть `buildComponent()` который вы не реализовали:

```
protected AppComponent buildComponent() {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .appModule(new AppModule(this))
        .build();
}
```

скриншот кода из статьи:
[image: скриншот кода из статьи]

PS: что бы облегчить себе работу в будущем и писать меньше бойлерплейт кода ознакомьтесь с [Dagger Android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html)

Comment: К сожалению этот проект у меня побился и слег с той же проблемой что и здесь  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/982303/more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-classes-dex . А так, да верно, не доглядел)

Comment: Как по мне по Даггер расписано лучше тут) https://habr.com/ru/post/344314/